# Variance of expected value, is the formula right?

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, expected-value, conditional-expectation

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2T7GdBVYd4&t=350) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsUvT6U45I0&t=302), I am seeing the variances of expected values calculated as this:

[image: img]

and this:

[image: img]

From which, I derived the formula:

$$\displaystyle\textrm{var}\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y] \big) = \sum\limits_{y} p_{Y}(y)\cdot(X - \mathbf E[X] \mid Y)^2$$

Is my formula correct?  Is there a name to it?  I cannot find it anywhere.  Thanks.

---

As per gunes' answer, for the discrete case:

$$\displaystyle\textrm{var}\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y] \big) = \sum\limits_{y} p_{Y}(y)\cdot\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y = y] - \mathbf E[X]\big)^2$$

For the continuous case:

$$\displaystyle\textrm{var}\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y] \big) = \int\limits_{y} f_{Y}(y)\cdot\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y = y] - \mathbf E[X]\big)^2dy$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typos/inconsistencies in your formula:

- The given sign *outside* the expected value parenthesis has no meaning
- LHS is a constant, but RHS is a function of $X$
- The expected value on LHS should have been $Y=y$ in order for you to calculate

Wrapping up, since $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ is a *function* on $Y$, we can call it as $g(Y)$, execute the [law of unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and write:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(g(Y))&=\mathbb E[(g(Y)-\mathbb E[g(Y)])^2]=\sum_y p_Y(y)(g(y)-E[g(Y)])^2\\&=\sum_y p_Y(y)(\mathbb E[X|Y=y]-\mathbb E[X])^2\end{align}$$

Comment: What given sign are you referring to?

Comment: the one in RHS the given sign is not inside any operator

Comment: You mean this $(X - \mathbf E[X] \mid Y)$?  How can it be fixed?

Comment: Oh right!  It cannot be fixed.

Comment: Is this right for the continuous version?

$$\displaystyle\textrm{var}\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y] \big) = \int\limits_{y} f_{Y}(y)\cdot\big(\mathbf E[X\mid Y = y] - \mathbf E[X]\big)^2\ dy$$

Comment: yes, but It's $dy$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!